# please explain DAX to me: FILTER in CALCULATE not overwriting slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

Can someone please explain why the FILTER in CACULATE statement example screenshotted does not overwite the slicer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is the last one, the reason of this behavior is the filter function code  :

```
 FILTER(DATE,DATE[Year]=2017)
```

wich evaluate the DATE table in the filter context, in our case the slicer value DATE[Year]=2018 before of the evaluation of the condition DATE[Year]=2017. So what we are really doing in our situation is filtering a subset of date table and not the all date table.

```
  FILTER((DATE in year 2018),DATE[Year]=2017)
```

In order to get the entire date table we use ALL(DATE) and therefore the FILTER should become

```
FILTER( ALL(DATE), DATE[Year] = 2017 )
```

Visit : https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filter-arguments-in-calculate/

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining Nacim, I understand now